# Redirect not working (Next.js app router v14, api route handler)

Tags: next.js

I have a useSignUp hook that makes a post fetch call to a route handler /auth/sign-up.
But the user is not redirected....

On success in the api route handler I return:

```
 return NextResponse.redirect(`${requestUrl.origin}/hidden/dashboard`, {
        status: 301,
      })
```

useSignUp hook:

```
const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    async (event: FormEvent) => {
      event.preventDefault()

      const validation = safeParse(SignUpSchema, {
        email: form.email,
        password: form.password,
        pnr: form.pnr,
      })

      if (validation.success) {
        setIsLoading(true)

        const response = await fetch('/api/auth/sign-up', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            form,
            token,
          }),
        })

        if (!response.ok) {
          const { createStandaloneToast } = await import('@chakra-ui/react')

          createStandaloneToast().toast({
            title: 'Sign up failed',
            status: 'error',
            duration: 9000,
            isClosable: true,
            position: 'top-right',
          })

          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      } else {
        const { createStandaloneToast } = await import('@chakra-ui/react')

        createStandaloneToast().toast({
          title: validation.issues[0].message,
          status: 'error',
          duration: 9000,
          isClosable: true,
          position: 'top-right',
        })
      }
    },
    [form]
  )
```

However, the user is not redirected to the given route but remains on the sign-up route?

Response:

```
~ file: useSignUp.tsx:54 ~ response: 
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/hidden/dashboard/sign-up/success', redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/hidden/dashboard/sign-up/success"
```

Any clues?

Comment: I mean I can work around it by adding a state eg. "completed", and then in the useSignUp hook I set this state to true after the successful fetch, and then I return this value from the hook, and in the form component I simply use router.push or redirect method to redirect when this state is true. This works, but it's more steps that I don't think should be needed.

Comment: I am having the same issues, this hack seems like it might work but also seems like just that, a hack.